# How to share variables between 2 API definitions in flask?

Tags: python, api, dictionary, flask, flask-restful

My code is like this. I am using Flask.

```
import *

def model_loading():
    ##function###

@app.route('training', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'OPTIONS'])
def training():
    ###function###
    model_loading()

@app.route('prediction', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'OPTIONS'])
def prediction():
    ###function###
    models_out.predict()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    models_out = model_loading()
```

In the above code `models_out` dictionary will load all my models in it when the execution starts. When a request for training a new model comes, after training again I will call the `model_loading` function to update the `models_out` dictionary with the new model. But while calling prediction request, the new model which I updated is not reflecting in `models_out` dictionary. How to handle this?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could define it as a global variable.

```
import *

models_out = None

def model_loading():
    ##function###

@app.route('training', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'OPTIONS'])
def training():
    global models_out
    ###function###
    models_out = model_loading()

@app.route('prediction', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'OPTIONS'])
def prediction():
    global models_out
    ###function###
    models_out.predict()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    models_out = model_loading()
```